# moment returning wrong difference between two dates even with timezone setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, ejs

I have this code :

```
  const effectDateParsed = moment(
    new Date( `${ effectDate.split( '-' )[2] }-${ effectDate.split( '-' )[1] }-${ effectDate.split( '-' )[0] }` ),
    'Africa/Tunis',
  );
  const deadlineDateParsed = moment(
    new Date( `${ deadlineDate.split( '-' )[2] }-${ deadlineDate.split( '-' )[1] }-${ deadlineDate.split( '-' )[0] }` ),
    'Africa/Tunis',
  );
  let remainingMonths = deadlineDateParsed.diff( effectDateParsed, 'months' );
```

now the results are different depending on the laptop's timezone. if the timezone is of the laptop is Africa/Tunisia

```
 remainingMonths = 6
```

if in Europe :

```
remainingMonths = 5
```

probably this have nothing with timezone too, here's what I tested :

1. manually set up the timezone to Africa/Tunisia, difference is correct
2. manually set up timezone to Europe/Paris, difference is incorrect
3. remove timezone setup from moment and retry 1 + 2, same results as if it's setup.

any idea on this?

Edit :
these are the two dates that I'm testing : 2021/01/01 and 2020/07/01 (YYYY/MM/DD)

Comment: i'd consider using a more robust date time library

Comment: I would, unfortunately it's not up to me

Comment: tho I'm open to suggestion here, if you recommend any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but setting the timezones explicitly like they did [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/), works for me for both `Africa/Tunis`and `Europe/Paris`:

```js
const diffEuropeZone = moment.tz("2021-01-01", "Europe/Paris").diff(moment.tz("2020-07-01","Europe/Paris"), "months");

const diffAfricaZone = moment.tz("2021-01-01", "Africa/Tunis").diff(moment.tz("2020-07-01","Africa/Tunis"), "months");

console.log("diff Europe-zone = ",diffEuropeZone); // logs 6
console.log("diff Africa-zone = ",diffAfricaZone ); // logs 6
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```